# Where can I find hemagglutination inhibition (HI) assay data?

Tags: virology, database, data, assay-development, influenza

I am looking for hemagglutination inhibition assay data for type A influenza virus. I've checked in databases such as fludb.com, however it seems to only have genetic data. A lot of the time, scientific papers don't include the HI assay data they used, so I was wondering if anyone knows where to find such data. I specifically need influenza type A HI assays, not influenza type B.

HI data comes in the form of titers (the reciprocal of the last well plate concentration of antibody that was able to inhibit the virus from binding to the blood sample and forming a shield on the well plate.)

Could someone please give me a link to a database with this information?

Thanks.

Comment: You can search in the NIAID Data Discovery Portal: https://data.niaid.nih.gov/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any universal database containing ongoing, widely representative HI assay output. The [Antigenic Cartography](http://www.antigenic-cartography.org) group has made available some historical datasets that were used in published articles, such as

- [Influenza A/H3N2 data published in Smith et al. 2004. Science 305:371-376](http://www.antigenic-cartography.org/Science-2004/)
- [Data from H1N1pdm09 assays in 2009/2010](http://www.antigenic-cartography.org/H1N1-mexican-2009/index.html) (click on the links for html/Excel/OpenDocument tables)
- [Data published in Koel et al. 2013. Science 342:976-979](http://www.antigenic-cartography.org/bjorn-h3-key-7/index.html)

Trevor Bedford et al. make their large set of historical HI data described in [Integrating influenza antigenic dynamics with molecular evolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3909918/) available in [DataDryad](https://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.rc515).